# Contradiction of propagation speed of gravitational waves with non-locality of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity, non-locality

Although LIGO at 2016 verified the speed of a traverse gravitational wave being the speed of light in a vacuum $c$ there is also the fact that gravity is a non-local phenomenon, meaning that it is not only affected by the distribution of matter and energy in a given point, but also by the distribution of matter and energy throughout the entire universe. Thus, gravity when examined with the whole universe being a covariant static field and frame of reference, is actually in an entangled state thus non-local and instantaneous "spooky action at a distance".

My question is, how general relativity deals with this non-locality problem of gravity and what quantum gravity theory has to say about it?

Comment: I don't think that's true. Gravity is a local phenomenon, and is not affected by the rest of the universe faster than light.

Comment: By definition every static field is instantaneous.

Comment: Do you realize that gravity of Andromeda galaxy pulls every instance of time on planet Earth?

Comment: *gravity of Andromeda galaxy pulls every instance of time on planet Earth?* Ah, but does it pull on us as it is currently or as it was when the "signal" was sent from Andromeda (which took $\ell/c$ seconds to get here)?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79450/25301. Probably others on this site as well?

Comment: *pulls every instance of time* What does *that* mean?

Comment: If Andromeda exploded "right now," the gravitational impact of that would not be felt by Earth until 2.5 million years from now – the propagation time of gravitational waves (and light) between there and here.  Hence gravity is still local.  Unless you are using the word *local* in a sense in not familiar with.

Comment: @RC I agree. Still, static force of Andromeda applied on our planet exists independent of time as if these two astronomical objects were a singlet thus entangled. How do you explain this?

Comment: I'm not a QM expert, but I think you may be conflating some unrelated ideas here. Two objects interacting at a distance does not constitute entanglement in the quantum sense. Entanglement means certain observable properties are correlated.  Also, the Earth doesn't interact with Andromeda directly. Earth interacts with the Gravity field directly next to itself, which is influenced by the field next to it, in a chain that's partially influenced by where Andromeda used to be 2.5 M yrs ago

Answer (score -2):

A possible explanation of gravity acting as a static non-local field throughout all of the universe is that the vacuum is a sea of gravitons condensate where all the gravitons are in an entangled state with each other acting like a giant singlet.

Of course we hit a wall here because the graviton renormalization problem.